# mysql_upgrade fails during mysql_fix_privilege_tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On a few computers, I am getting consistent failures when running mysql_upgrade. The upgrade shouldn't actually do anything, we just run it as a matter of course when upgrading our application. This is the latest mariadb 10.1.26. The upgrade script runs as the current user which is who mariadb is running as and owns all the directories. Any ideas what could possibly cause this. We have tried fresh OS install but the problem doesn't go away. Similar computers of the same type and OS run just fine.

```
2017-08-07 09:12:22,343   INFO  c.c.c.m.u.BaseCmd Phase 3/6: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
2017-08-07 09:12:22,343   INFO  c.c.c.m.u.BaseCmd ERROR 1025 (HY000) at line 564: Error on rename of '.\mysql\#sql-2a4_b' to '.\mysql\user' (errno: 13 "Permission denied")
2017-08-07 09:12:22,343   INFO  c.c.c.m.u.BaseCmd FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Comment: Sounds like the OS "user" used to do the install and upgrade was not 'root'.

Comment: It most definitely is the DB root user

Comment: Not the DB "root", the Operating system "root".

Comment: Right, the install happens as a non-root user and the upgrade also happens as a non-root user the database is installed into the user's AppData directory and the upgrade happens there.

Comment: That explains the permission problems.

Comment: How so? This process is performed on hundreds of computers. There are a few laptops that seem to fail like this.